# How to select an exact region inside a map polygon leaflet

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Here is the whole code

```
poi = readOGR("costa_rica_poi.shp")
poi2= readOGR("CRI_adm1.shp")

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("El mapa"),

  leafletOutput("mapa") ,
  selectInput("mapa", label = "Seleccione el Tipo", choices = c("San Jose","Cartago","Heredia","Limon","Alajuela","Guanacaste","Puntarenas")),
  selectInput("p", label = "Seleccione el Tipo", choices = poi@data$NAME)
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  base1=reactive({
    poi@data$NAME == input$p
  })

  output$mapa <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>% setView(lat = 9.5, -83, zoom=7) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = poi@coords[base1(),1],
                 lat = poi@coords[base1(),2])  %>% addPolygons(data=poi2)



  })
}
```

And what I got is the next:

[image]

> What is it that I want to do?

"poi" is the .shp with the information of the country, and poi2 is the file with the lat & lng of each state

What I got above was the polygon of all the states, but what I really want is that when I select, for example, "San Jose" on the slide below, the polygon appears only on that state, not on the whole country, and when I select the state "Cartago", the polygon appears only in Cartago, not i the other states and so on...

How can I do this?

Update: The name of the vector with the states is "NAME_1"